# Sails populate field does not return with correct results

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have a User model like this:

```
/**
* User.js
*
* @description :: TODO: You might write a short summary of how this model works and what it represents here.
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/

module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    firstName: 'string',
    lastName: 'string',
    fullName: {
      type: 'string',
      index: true
    },
    loginMethod: 'integer',
    emailAddress: {
      type: 'string',
      unique: true
    },
    password: 'string',
    friends: {
      collection: 'User'
    },
    tallys: {
      collection: 'Tally',
      via: 'associatedUser'
    },
    friendsTallys: {
      collection: 'Tally',
      via: 'invitedUsers'
    },
    toJson: function() {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      delete obj.friends;
      delete obj.tallys;
      delete obj.friendsTallys;
      return obj;
    }
  },

  beforeCreate: function(values, cb) {
    // Set the full name property using the first name and the last name
    values.fullName = values.firstName + " " + values.lastName;
    cb();
  }

};
```

I have a Tally model like this:

```
/**
* Tally.js
*
* @description :: TODO: You might write a short summary of how this model works and what it represents here.
 * @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/

module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    associatedUser: {
      model: 'User'
    },
        type: 'integer',
    yesThisCount: 'integer',
    noThatCount: 'integer',
    caption: 'string',
    photos: {
      collection: 'Photo'
    },
    invitedUsers: {
      collection: 'User'
    }
  }
};
```

I have a bootstrap js file like this:

```
/**
 * Bootstrap
 * (sails.config.bootstrap)
 *
 * An asynchronous bootstrap function that runs before your Sails app gets lifted.
 * This gives you an opportunity to set up your data model, run jobs, or perform some special logic.
 *
 * For more information on bootstrapping your app, check out:
 * http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.bootstrap.html
 */

var async = require('async');

module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {

  // It's very important to trigger this callback method when you are finished
  // with the bootstrap!  (otherwise your server will never lift, since it's waiting on the bootstrap)

  /**
   * Make some fake users for testing
   * These will not be used for logging in.
   * This is just to check addFriend and searching
   */

  var asyncCreateUsers = [];
  var asyncCreatePhotos = [];
  var asyncCreateTallys = [];

  var usersJS = [];
  var usersSails = [];

  var talliesJS = [];

  var yesNoPhotoSails;
  var thisPhotoSails;
  var thatPhotoSails;

  // create the user javascript objects
  for (idx = 0; idx < 5; idx ++) {
    usersJS.push({
      firstName: 'Test0' + idx + '_first',
      lastName: 'Test0' + idx + '_last',
      emailAddress: 'test0' + idx + '@test.com',
      password: 'testing',
      loginMethod: 0
    });
  }

  // push each thing into the asyncTasks array
  _.each(usersJS, function(user) {
    asyncCreateUsers.push(function(callback){
       User.create(user).exec(function(error, user){
        if (error) {
            sails.log.error("whoops, user not created");
        } else {
          sails.log.info("user created");
          usersSails.push(user);
        }
        callback();
        }
      );
    });
  });

  async.parallel(asyncCreateUsers, function() {
    // Finish created users in sails
    sails.log.info('created users, now create photos');

    // Make them all friends.

    createPhotosAsynchronously();

  });

  function createPhotosAsynchronously() {
     // Create my photos
    var yesNoPhoto = {
      path: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/6f/Yoda_Attack_of_the_Clones.png'
    };

    var thisPhoto = {
      path: 'http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11118/111184078/4610796-0849145928-4-Ana.jpg'
    };

    var thatPhoto = {
      path: 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/1345598281_Episode_4_Luke_Skywalker_1.jpg'
    };

    asyncCreatePhotos.push(function(callback){
      Photo.create(yesNoPhoto).exec(function(error, photo){
        if (error) {
          sails.log.error('whoops, yesno photo not created');
        } else {
          yesNoPhotoSails = photo;
        }
        callback();
      });
    });

    asyncCreatePhotos.push(function(callback){
      Photo.create(thisPhoto).exec(function(error, photo){
        if (error) {
          sails.log.error('whoops, this photo not created');
        } else {
          thisPhotoSails = photo;
        }
        callback();
      });
    });

    asyncCreatePhotos.push(function(callback){
      Photo.create(thatPhoto).exec(function(error, photo){
        if (error) {
          sails.log.error('whoops, that photo not created');
        } else {
          thatPhotoSails = photo;
        }
        callback();
      });
    });

    async.parallel(asyncCreatePhotos, function(){
      // Finished creating photos, create tallys now.
      sails.log.info('created photos, now create tallys');
      createTallysAsynchronously();
    });
  }

  function createTallysAsynchronously() {

    var userIds = _.pluck(usersSails.slice(), 'id');
    // create the tallies javascript objects
    for (idx = 0; idx < usersSails.length; idx ++) {

      talliesJS.push({
        associatedUser: usersSails[idx],
        type: 0,
        yesThisCount: 0,
        noThatCount: 0,
        caption: 'YesNo',
        photos: [yesNoPhotoSails]
      });
      talliesJS.push({
        associatedUser: usersSails[idx],
        type: 1,
        yesThisCount: 0,
        noThatCount: 0,
        caption: 'ThisThat',
        photos: [thisPhotoSails, thatPhotoSails]
      });
    }

    _.each(talliesJS, function(tally) {
      asyncCreateTallys.push(function(callback){
        Tally.create(tally).exec(function(error, createdTally){
          if (error) {
            sails.log.error("tally did not create");
          } else {
            Tally.findOne({id: createdTally.id}).populate('invitedUsers').exec(
              function(e,r){
                var associatedUser = r.associatedUser;
                sails.log.info('associated User: ' + associatedUser);
                var ids = _.reject(userIds, function(id) {return id == associatedUser});
                _.each(ids, function(id){
                  r.invitedUsers.add(id);
                  r.save(function(err){sails.log.info('saved after adding invitedUser: ' + id)});
                });

                callback();
            });
          }
        });
      });
    });

    async.parallel(asyncCreateTallys, function() {
      // FIN
      sails.log.info('created tallys, finished');
      cb();
    });

  }

};
```

I have a login method which looks like this:

```
var loginUserFunction = function(){
                        User.findOne({emailAddress: user.emailAddress})
                        .populate("tallys")
                        .populate('friendsTallys')
                        .populate('friends')
                        .exec(function(err, found) {
                                if(err) {
                                        sails.log.error("There was an error looking for the user: " + JSON.stringify(err));
                                        return res.serverError({error: sails.config.errors.SERVER_ERROR});
                                }
                                if(found == null) {
                                        sails.log.info("Could not find user with email address: " + user.emailAddress);
                                        return res.badRequest({error: sails.config.errors.INVALID_EMAIL});
                                }
                                if(found && found.loginMethod != user.loginMethod)
                                {
                                        sails.log.info("The user tried to login using the wrong method!");
                                        return res.badRequest({error: sails.config.errors.INVALID_LOGIN_METHOD});
                                }

                                var friends = found.friends;

                                var friendsTallysIds = _.pluck(found.friendsTallys, 'id');

                                // We populated tallys and friendsTallys but we need to get the fields in those tallys to be populated so we have to query directly for the Tallys
                                Tally.find(_.pluck(found.tallys, 'id'))
                                .populate('associatedUser')
                                .populate('invitedUsers')
                                .populate('photos')
                                .exec(function(err, tallys) {
                                        if(err){
                                                sails.log.error("There was an error getting the tallys for the user: " + JSON.stringify(err));
                                                return res.serverError({error: sails.config.errors.SERVER_ERROR});
                                        }
                                        if(tallys == null)
                                        {
                                                tallys = [];
                                        }

                                        Tally.find(_.pluck(found.friendsTallys, 'id'))
                                        .populate('associatedUser')
                                        .populate('invitedUsers')
                                        .populate('photos')
                                        .exec(function(err, friendsTallys) {
                                                if(err){
                                                        sails.log.error("There was an error getting the friends' tallys for the user: " + JSON.stringify(err));
                                                        return res.serverError({error: sails.config.errors.SERVER_ERROR});
                                                }
                                                if(friendsTallys == null)
                                                {
                                                        friendsTallys = [];
                                                }

                                                sails.log.info("The user was found: " + user.emailAddress);

                                                // Generate an auth token for the user
                                                var userAuthToken = EncryptionService.generateUserAuthToken(found);

                                                // Set the token in the response headers
                                                res.set('userAuthToken', userAuthToken);
                                                // Remove the tallys, friendTallys, friends from the found object

                                                // Subscribe the user to this own model
                                                User.subscribe(req.socket, found);

                                                // Subscribe to own tallys
                                                Tally.subscribe(req.socket, tallys);

                                                // Subscribe to Friends' Tallys
                                                Tally.subscribe(req.socket, friendsTallys);

                                                // Send the response
                                                res.json({
                                                        user: found,
                                                        tallys: tallys,
                                                        friendsTallys: friendsTallys,
                                                        friends: friends
                                                });
                                        });
                                });
                        });
                }
```

My problem is that the friendsTallys field in my user objects is showing only 2 tallys when in fact there should be 8 tallys because I create 2 tallys for each user and then invite all the other users for each tally. Furthermore, those 2 tallys in the friendsTalls is the same tallys in the Tallys field. This is a view of my breakpoint:
[image: Breakpoint image]

Thanks for the help. If you need more info/code/context just let me know.

Comment: You must attach your code here not the screenshots.

Comment: The screenshot is to provide context of my problem if that is not clear. The breakpoint is at the line and all the variables and their values can be seen on the left. As you can see, tallys and friendstallys have the same values, which is my issue. I believe that I have provided all the relevant code needed. If anyone needs additional code for helping me debug this, I would be glad to provide it.

Comment: Your code needs to go in the question, not on 3rd party sites.

Comment: Sure I can edit it. But it is really kind of long. This just seemed a lot neater, guys.

Comment: Is the question clear enough for you? @meagar